# Finding multiple minimums and adding new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df that looks like the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Amount': [1,2,3,4,6,7],
                'Name': ['person1', 'person1' ,'person2'     ,'person2','person3','person3'],})
```

What I am trying to do is create a third column that displays the minimum amount for each person. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is using [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine), which is so useful that I strongly recommend reading the section of the docs linked there.  You can get a `Series` with the minimum values per person:

```
>>> df.groupby("Name")["Amount"].min()
Name
person1    1
person2    3
person3    6
Name: Amount, dtype: int64
```

Or the same information as a `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df.groupby("Name", as_index=False)["Amount"].min()
      Name  Amount
0  person1       1
1  person2       3
2  person3       6

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Or if you really want to add a column to your original dataframe, you can use `transform`:

```
>>> df["Minimum_Amount"] = df.groupby("Name")["Amount"].transform('min')
>>> df
   Amount     Name  Minimum_Amount
0       1  person1               1
1       2  person1               1
2       3  person2               3
3       4  person2               3
4       6  person3               6
5       7  person3               6

[6 rows x 3 columns]
```